# GREP with wrapped phrase(one sentence spanning multiple lines) - Java

Tags: java, grep

I am trying to figure out how to make a grep method that can read wrapped  phrases from up-to infinity lines(That is a sentence or string spanning multiple lines of a given text file) in java. Here is my current code for the grep function:

```
public static void grep() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Cabbages.txt"));
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = "", input = "", wrappedPhrase = "", modified = "";
    int c = 0, foundCount = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    System.out.print("Please enter something you want to grep: ");
    input = in.nextLine();
    while((line = f.readLine()) != null) {
        c++;
        found = false;
        int index = line.indexOf(input);
        while(index >= 0) {
            modified = "<" + line.substring(line.indexOf(input), (line.indexOf(input)+input.length())) + ">";
            found = true;
            index = line.indexOf(input, index + 1);
            foundCount++;
        }
        if(found) {
            System.out.println("Found on line: " + c + ", which is: " + line.replace(input, modified));
        }
    }
    if(foundCount <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, the input string of: \"" + input + "\" was not found within the given file.");
    }else {
        System.out.println("In total, the input string of: \"" + input + "\"" + " was found " + foundCount + " time(s).");
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you actually running into?  Do you just have a normal grep that you want to make multi-line?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: It looks like you are reading a line, searching it, then discarding it to read the next line. To find something across lines you will have to retain _at least **two**_ lines such as `currentLine = f.readLine(); nextLine = f.readLine();` with appropriate checking for end of input.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the problem still remains that the strong input could be more than just over two lines of code, it could be over an “inifinite” number of lines without a specific end of input.

Comment: why I said "at least"... maybe the way to go is with Java NIO memory mapped files — [here's an intro](https://howtodoinjava.com/java-7/nio/java-nio-2-0-memory-mapped-files-mappedbytebuffer-tutorial/)

Comment: Ok, I will check it out and see if it helps.